# What are the restrictions on seq.int?

Tags: r

The `seq` man page states the following (emphasis mine):

> ### Description
>
> Generate regular sequences. `seq` is a standard generic with a default method. `seq.int` is a primitive which can be much faster ***but has a few restrictions***.

The page doesn't actually describe what those restrictions are, though. Here's every other mention of `seq.int` there:

> ### Arguments
>
> [...]
>
> `length.out` desired length of the sequence. A non-negative number, which for `seq` and `seq.int` will be rounded up if fractional.
>
> [...]
>
> ### Details
>
> [...]
>
> The interpretation of the unnamed arguments of `seq` and `seq.int` is not standard, and it is recommended always to name the arguments when programming.
>
> [...]
>
> `seq.int` is an internal generic which dispatches on methods for "`seq`" based on the class of the first supplied argument (before argument matching).
>
> `seq.int`, `seq_along` and `seq_len` are primitive.
>
> ### Value
>
> `seq.int` and the default method of `seq` for numeric arguments return a vector of type "`integer`" or "`double`": programmers should not rely on which.

Other than stating that `seq.int` dispatches `seq` according to the class of its first argument, I don't see any "restrictions".

So, what are these restrictions?

Comment: Good point, I'll add that all examples given in the help file for `seq` work all the same with `seq.int`, except dramatically faster, so it's not clear why use `seq` at all. Might be related to https://twitter.com/BrodieGaslam/status/1196792003813621761

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper that's precisely why I asked: I've been using `seq.int` out of habit, but saw that comment in the man page and now I'd like to know if I've been taking any "risks" in using it thoughtlessly.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper and for the record, "the docs were never updated" would be an entirely acceptable and unsurprising answer.

Comment: I found this though it doesn't make much sense to me : https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/History-of-seq-and-seq-int-td2720129.html

Comment: I'd say "For seq (only), up to two of from, to and by can be supplied as complex values provided length.out or along.with is specified. More generally, the default method of seq will handle classed objects with methods for the Math, Ops and Summary group generics." explains a restriction. You can do `seq(from = 0 + 1i, to = 10 + 1i, length.out = 11)` but you can't do the same with `seq.int`.

Comment: @Roland - maybe you should add that comment as an answer

Answer (score 7):

`seq` is a standard generic function written in R. `seq.int` is a primitive function written in C. While both of them are written to do the same job, due do the quirks of their platforms, they can sometimes have certain restrictions. The following is an example.

[image]

Note that this is from an old version of `R` and is fixed in the current versions. These kinds of bugs have been observed throughout the development of R and they have been patched as soon as possible. The current versions of [seq](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/034b83ee81d747bbd3bf1a3f9fd121ecd4f493a3/src/library/base/R/seq.R) and [seq.int](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/39954f65eb16ce07f0d64e9ce12c378b2a03da41/src/main/seq.c) now look almost identical. So, there should not be any more restrictions on `seq.int`.

Comment: thanks for your answer, can you post code (e.g. a reprex) instead instead of an image, and include Roland's comment in your answer (if he doesn't post his own answer meanwhile). I can also edit your answer and do it myself if that's fine for you.

Comment: You're not supposed to put image for code