# speed of generating sequence from 1 to N

Tags: r, seq

I am curious about the speed of generating a sequence from `1` to `N`, and found that the performance differ a lot

```
library(microbenchmark)
N <- 1000
microbenchmark(unit = "relative",
               1:N,
               seq(N),
               seq(1,N))
```

showing

```
Unit: relative
      expr min lq     mean median   uq       max neval
       1:N NaN  1  1.00000      1  1.0  1.000000   100
    seq(N) Inf 38 25.50617     39 21.0  9.818182   100
 seq(1, N) Inf 43 29.89506     44 23.5 29.181818   100
```

I was thinking `seq(N)` and `seq(1,N)` might be close in terms of speed, but the benchmark surprised me. Also, `1:N` is far faster than `seq(N)`, which is also surprising to me. Can anyone explain a bit regarding their performance difference? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Dupe-oid: [Why is seq(x) so much slower than 1:length(x)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24215077/why-is-seqx-so-much-slower-than-1lengthx) (not much google-fu needed: "seq speed R"). Related: [What are the restrictions on seq.int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59378862/what-are-the-restrictions-on-seq-int)

Comment: Related reading: [History of seq and seq.int](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2010-October/058725.html)

Comment: @Henrik Thanks, Henrik! Do you have any clue why `seq(N)` and `seq(1,N)` differ so much?

Comment: Both `seq(from)` and `seq(from, to)` call `seq.default`. From a quick glance at the code it seems like `seq(from)` is evaluated on line 11 (`1L:from`), and `seq(from, to)` on line 42 (`from:to`). Seems like the stuff between those lines may generate the difference.